# What does big E mean in this equation?

Tags: notation

What does E mean in this equation?

$$G_i(x_i) = \sup\limits_{\tau \geq1}\frac{E\left[\sum\limits_{t=0}^{\tau-1}{r_i(x_i(t))\beta^t\;\bigg\vert\;x_i(0)=x_i}\right]}{E\left[\sum\limits_{t=0}^{\tau-1}{\beta^t\;\bigg\vert\;x_i(0)=x_i}\right]}$$

[gittins index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPgE9m.png)

Comment: Please write your equations in text instead of linking to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the "expectation" or "expected value."

You can read more on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) as to what expectation is, but essentially $E[X]$ denotes the expected value of a random variable $X$; you can extend this to conditional probabilities as well.

I was able to discern this from the [Gittins index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gittins_index#Mathematical_definition) Wikipedia page; $\langle X \rangle$ is another common notation for expected value of a random variable $X$.

Comment: It refers to expectation, expected value or mathematical expectation. In this case is a conditional expectation. It does not refer to average value. If you have a i.i.d. sample $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$, from a random variable $X$ with Expected Value $E(X)$, the Average Value $\bar X=(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)/n$ is an estimator for the (often unknown) theoretical quantity $E(X)$. Expected value and average value are 2 distinct notions.

Comment: Fair enough, I was thinking from a more intuitive standpoint (i.e. the value taken on average by the r.v.), since OP evidently hasn't seen this enough to be familiar with the notion. But I'll go ahead and remove that since apparently people take issue with it.